# Is a map which commutes with the codifferential an isometry?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms, symmetry, isometry

$\newcommand{\M}{\mathcal{M}}$
$\newcommand{\N}{\mathcal{N}}$

Let $\M,\N$ be smooth oriented $d$-dimensional Riemannian manifolds. Let $f:\M \to \N$ be smooth, and let $\delta=d^*$ be the adjoint of the exterior derivative.

Supopse that:

1. $f^*\delta \omega=\delta f^*\omega$ for every differential form $\omega$ on $\N$ of every degree.
2. $df$ is invertible everywhere on $\M$.

> Is it true that $f$ is an isometry?

In dimesnion $d=1$ I was able to prove this with an easy computation. For $d \ge 2$ the calculation seems to get more involved.

Note that up to signs $\delta=\star d \star$. Can we show any such $f$ commutes with the Hodge dual? If this is the case, then $f$ [must be an isometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2300970/a-map-which-commutes-with-hodge-dual-is-conformal).

*Comment:* I am not sure the requirement that $df$ is invertible is necessary. Indeed, if $\omega$ is a $1$-form on $\N$, then $\delta \omega \circ f=f^*\delta \omega=\delta f^*\omega$, so the LHS does not involve an action by the differential of $f$, while the RHS does involve such an action. In particular, the constant map does not satisfy the equation. (For dimension $1$, the invertibility assumption is indeed not needed).

**Edit:**

Here is a partial answer. I still hope there is a more slick argument.

First, the condition $f^*\delta \omega=\delta f^*\omega$ for one forms implies $f$ is a *harmonic morphism*, i.e. it preserves harmonicity of functions under precomposition. It is known that such maps, between equidimensional manifolds, must be weakly conformal, that is at every point $x \in \M$, the differential $df_x$ is either a linear conformal map or zero. So, if we assume $df \neq 0$, we are done; Our map is conformal, and now it is not hard to see it must be an isometry.

Can we relax the requirement $df \neq 0$?